# ffmpeg watermark video while uploading

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have a CMS system for uploading videos using ffmpeg, I cannot figure a way to watermark the videos every time I'm getting errors (video cannot play) or  error encoding etc.
The command for processing the videos is:

```
$shell     = shell_exec("$ffmpeg_b -y -i $video_file_full_path -vcodec libx264 -preset {$pt->config->convert_speed} -filter:v scale=426:-2 -crf 26 $video_output_full_path_240 2>&1");
```

I have tried this command also:

```
$shell     = shell_exec("$ffmpeg_b -y -i $video_file_full_path -vcodec libx264 -preset {$pt->config->convert_speed} -filter:v scale=426:-2 -crf 26 -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:10' $video_output_full_path_240 2>&1");
```

This not seems to work.. is there any way I can troubleshoot this ?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Does the command work without PHP being involved?

Comment: The command is being executed onto the cloud hosting, I'm not getting any errors just videos does not play and saying error encoding ..

Comment: ` I'm not getting any errors` You are getting errors, you're just not seeing them. Pipe the ffmpeg log to a file and see what is said.

Comment: as I said its not getting errors at all just the video file is not playable.

Answer (score 0):

## Problems

If you were to refer to the output from `ffmpeg` you would encounter two errors:

- Option `filter:v` (set stream filtergraph) cannot be applied to input url `watermark.png` -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
  Error parsing options for input file `watermark.png`.
- Filtergraph `'scale=426:-2'` was specified through the `-vf`/`-af`/`-filter` option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
  `-vf`/`-af`/`-filter` and `-filter_complex` cannot be used together for the same stream.

## Solutions

- Option placement matters. You are mixing placement of input and output options. Placement must be as follows:

```
    ffmpeg [global options] [input0 options] -i input0 [input1 options] -i input1 [output options] output
```

- Do not mix `-vf` and `-filter_complex`. Do all filtering in one `-filter_complex` instance.

## Example

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=426:-2[bg];[bg][1]overlay=10:10" -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 26 output.mp4
```